# Node: How to get the dirname where a script was called from?

Tags: node.js, command-line, directory

Say I run a Node script from `/foo/bar`, though the script itself is located somewhere else (e.g. `node_modules`).  Is there a way to get the working directory where the script was called from, i.e. `/foo/bar`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you want is [`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd), which returns the current working directory of the Node.js process.